# PagerView with images crashes

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have PagerView and I want to make it behave like slider with ability to show large images. Problems is that after swiping a couple of photos it crashes. Another topics on stackoverflow says that I have to use `destroyItem` method, but its deprecated.

Is there any another workarounds to solve the issue ?

here is MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    CirclePageIndicator circlePageIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.titles);
    circlePageIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);

}
}
```

here is adapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    int[] imageId = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4, R.drawable.image5};

    public CustomAdapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;

    }


    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();

        View viewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_item, container, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) viewItem.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        ((ViewPager)container).addView(viewItem);

        return viewItem;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return imageId.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return view == ((View)object);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object o) {
        View view = (View)o;
        ((ViewPager) collection).removeView(view);
        view = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: change PagerAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this); to CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this);

Comment: thanks for pointing out!